# alternative for placeholder in order to work at internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer

### Placeholder can't be used in internet explorer.

1) When i tested the 1ts one it works in chrome, firefox but does not work in internet explorer.

2) when i tested 2nd, it works well on chrome, firefox and also internet explorer.

The problem I'm facing here is when i add (ID="txtUserID") this to (2) it does not work on internet explorer. But i need the (ID="txtUserID") this in order to use it in the back-end.

Any solution for this?

```
****************1*******************

<asp:TextBox ID="txtUserID" CssClass="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username " Width="100%" Height="36px" runat="server" Text="adminuser" MaxLength="16" />

****************2*******************

<asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" Width="100%" Height="36px" MaxLength="16" Text="adminuser" runat="server" value="Username......" placeholder="Username" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;"> </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: edit your question and add the code which you have added in comment

Comment: yes i did ealier in the first place but it does not show the code but shows the plain words

Comment: you can now remove the above comment which has code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate to placeholder: Use **onblur** function of jquery and change **value** of text box accordingly.

```html
 

   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    Enter your name: <input id="#yourID" type="text" value="placeholder" onfocus="myFunction(this)" onblur="addPlaceHolder(this)">


    <script>
   function myFunction(x) {
    x.value = "";
}
function addPlaceHolder(thisEle){
  
if(thisEle.value=='Place Holder' || thisEle.value=='')
thisEle.value='Place Holder';
}
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: check above code .I have added snippet.Modify for additional logics if required.

Comment: how about the id? because i need to run a login function

Comment: a small question, rather than using <input can i use <asp:textbox?

Comment: Yes .Only add those onblur ,onfocus functions .Thats it.It will work.